# PHP function updating all title fields for every task in whole table

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update the title as a single database task entry. My function currently updates the titles of all the tasks in the table.

```
public function update(User $user, Task $task, Request $request) {
    $data = $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
    ]);

    Auth::user()->tasks()->update([
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'is_complete' => 0,
        'updated_at' => '2020-01-30 10:39:33',
        'created_at' => '2020-01-30 10:39:33'
    ]);

    session()->flash('status', 'Task Completed!');

    return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
}
```

Comment: you have to use unique id to update specific task like this
`->where('id', $data['id'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```php
 public function update(User $user, Task $task, Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
        Auth::user()->tasks()->find($task->id)->update([
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'is_complete' => 0,
            'updated_at' => '2020-01-30 10:39:33',
            'created_at' => '2020-01-30 10:39:33',
        ]);
        session()->flash('status', 'Task Completed!');

        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

add `find($task->id)`

Comment: ErrorException 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$id

Answer (score 1):

Use `where('id', $task->id)` on Task eloquent builder:

```php
Auth::user()->tasks()->where('id', $task->id)->update([
       'title' => $data['title'],
       'is_complete' => 0,
       'updated_at' => '2020-01-30 10:39:33',
       'created_at' => '2020-01-30 10:39:33'
])
```

Comment: Thank you that does seem to work however I'm getting this instead of the return page

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: 0 (SQL: update "tasks" set "0" = 1, "updated_at" = 2020-01-30 12:55:50 where "tasks"."user_id" = 1 and "tasks"."user_id" is not null and "id" = 7)

Comment: @ozeol can u post your update code, It seems you are passing array with `0` as key

Comment: Auth::user()->tasks()->where('id', $task->id)->update([
            $task->update([
                  'title' => $data['title'],

                  'is_complete' => 0,
                  'updated_at' => '2020-01-30 10:39:33',
                  'created_at' => '2020-01-30 10:39:33'
              ])]);

Comment: why are u put the `$task->update()` in `update()` method? I think you can just paste my code.

Comment: @ozeol can you check my update code once and this is also right answer